# Spark-Java: Build the doc example from the command line

Tags: java, rest, maven, compiler-errors, spark-java

I'm trying to build the simple example in the Spark-Java [documentation](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#getting-started) from the command line.  I've added the dependency to my pom.xml and I'm using the code from the first example:

Added the dependency:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
<version>2.5.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Tried compiling and running this code:

```
import static spark.Spark.*;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        get("/hello", (req, res) -> "Hello World");
    }
}
```

But when I attempt to run this I get the errors:

```
error: ')' expected
error: illegal start of expression
error: ';' expected
```

The commands I'm using to compile and run my project are:

```
mvn compile
mvn -q exec:java
```

Why am I getting these errors when I attempt to run this from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that **the sources are compiled as Java 8**.

This is is done [by defining the `maven.compiler.source` and `maven.compiler.target` properties](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) in `pom.xml`:

```
<properties>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Comment: Thanks.  That did it.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use lambda expressions like `(req, res) -> "Hello World"`, Java8 is needed. You're either using an older Java version or Maven is using a compiler version lower than 1.8.